# Difference between 単独で and 単独に

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

In an online dictionary for [単独](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8D%98%E7%8B%AC/#jn-140459), 単独 is used seemingly as an adverb in two example sentences, but with different particles:

> 「単独で登頂する」
> 「単独に存在する」

99% of other 単独 examples online use で. Since this is a very reliable online dictionary in my experience, what is the grammar of using 単独に here?  Is 単独 treated as a different part of speech in 単独に versus 単独で?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's definitely some freedom of choice, but で suggests agency (by whatever is "independent"), whereas に suggests passivity/staticity. It's not by chance that 単独で is used with 登頂する, and 単独に is used with 存在する.

Other examples I found on the Shonagon corpus:

> 『幻想交響曲』のみが    単独に     コンサートで演奏される

に feels best here, since 幻想交響曲, which is what is played independently, is the object of action. (The passive structure here is irrelevant, I would still use に in 『幻想交響曲』を単独に演奏する.) 『幻想交響曲』を単独**で**演奏する, on the other hand, sounds a bit more like "[someone] is playing it by themselves", although to me, both interpretations are valid.

> 夫が    単独で     移住するケース

で sounds better here, since the independence describes the agent, 夫.